# How to write to subsections in CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have to modify the following class.

```
class csv_writer:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def write_data(self,variable,value):      
         data = [variable,value]
         with open(self.filename,'a') as c_writer:
             writer = csv.writer(c_writer, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, lineterminator='\n')
             writer.writerow(data)
```

I have to add an argument "subsection" to write_data() so that it creates a subsection in the csv and writes data under that subsection.

```
obj = csv_writer('List.csv')
obj.write_data('TEST1','sample1',27)
obj.write_data('TEST2','sample3',12)  # to group2 :)
obj.write_data('TEST1','sample2',34)  # again to group1 :(
obj.write_data('TEST2','sample4',32)
```

For examplee, it has to create a CSV file like this one for the above:

```
TEST1
sample1,27
sample2,34

TEST2
sample3,12
sample4,32
```

Is it possible to implement this kind of subsections using csv module? I have done a quick search but didn't find any..

Comment: It doesn't look like you've explored all the options. Try holding the different subsections in your implementation (not in that of the csv module), and concat them only when you're done receiving input.

Comment: @ Tal Thanks. Know that. I was wondering if i can update the csv as and when data is received. :)

Answer (score 0):

From your source code, it seems you want to write `section`,`variable` and `value`. So it seems to be like `INI file` format. If so, consider using `ConfigParser` module.
Even you don't want this, you can get a hint to write your own `csv_writer` class(like there need to be "set" and "write" method etc...)

For example:

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.add_section('TEST1')
config.add_section('TEST2')
config.set('TEST1','sample1',27)
config.set('TEST2','sample3',12)
config.set('TEST1','sample2',34)
config.set('TEST2','sample4',32)

with open("./sample.ini", 'w') as fp:
    config.write(fp)
```

output:

```
[TEST1]
sample1 = 27
sample2 = 34

[TEST2]
sample3 = 12
sample4 = 32
```